# Non intrusive pop up reminder (Random) in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, productivity, reminders, todo

Like most of us, I have more information that I can remember in my head, (from work todo list, home todo list, honey todo list, kids schedule, code snippets, reminders, shortcuts that I want to remember, things that I would like to read later). I struggle with keeping all these in my head. I have tried virtually all todo lists, note taking apps (that I can think of), without much success.

I am looking for a **non-intrusive pop up reminder** that would **randomly** show short notes on my windows desktop, to help me remember that. I am envisioning random pop-up notification for my personal notes.

There used be a **Growl for Windows**, that shows such popups, without interfering with workflow. It is not developed anymore with Windows 10 notifications. But I am using Windows 7.

Things I have *tried so far with little success*:

1. Task Scheduler to show messages (it is not easy to add messages)
2. OneNote/Evernote to keep all my notes, but I forget to look at that!
3. Sticky Notes (but it gets overwhelmingly long)
4. Some free reminder apps, but they need to set to fixed time/date, I am looking for a **random note reminders**.

I am looking for a simple, random non-intrusive pop up that randomly shows notes from a source file (preferably text file).

Comment: What about "todo" via the use of Slack?

Comment: "Non-intrusive pop up reminder" sounds a bit like an oxymoron to me.  Perhaps some more details will help clarify.  What does "non-intrusive" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I love **Marxio Timer for Windows**

It seems to be no longer supported and has disappeared from a lot of download sites, but if you [search for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=marxio+timer) you can still find it, e.g [here](http://www.softsea.com/review/Marxio-Timer.html) (April 2018).